# Retrieve data from remote server in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Say I have a stored procedure that gets data from another database on another server like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [DatabaseServer].[DatabaseName].dbo.dbPerson
```

I can setup a linked server and it works as I would expect.  Is there a way to connect to a remote server in a stored procedure without creating a linked server i.e. by specifying the connection string along with the username and password to connect with?

I know that I can do this with SSIS.  I wandered if it is possible in a stored procedure.

Comment: read about [opendatasource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx).

Comment: and about [openrowset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Zohar said you can use opendatasrouce like this

```
Select 
*
from 
OPENDATASOURCE(
             'SQLOLEDB',
             'Data Source=_SQL_SERVER_NAME_;User ID=_LOGIN_;Password=_PASSWORD_'
             ).[DatabaseName].dbo.dbPerson
    WHERE ...
```

or you can use different providers and put different connection strings

Comment: Thanks. Does opendatasource work out of the box or are there any prerequisites?

Comment: Out of the box, no prerequisites